# React and IE9: Only renders initially when dev-tools is open

Tags: reactjs

Im running react 16.8+ on Internet Explorer 9.

Initially the page renders as blank without any react app in the root element. 
When I open the F12 dev tools and refresh the page it renders fine.
When I close the dev tools and refresh it also renders fine.

Does anyone have an idea why initially the page is not rendered?

Comment: Why would you use a browser that dates back to 2011 with React 16.8, which was released in early Feb. 2019? Is it due to a specific reason/constraint? Although IE 9 is supposed to still be supported in React 16+, it would not surprise me if the compatibility was not perfect.

Comment: I have various professional reasons for that.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently since redux is trying to console log the app freezes, since console log is only available when dev-tools is open. Therefor add the following polyfill in your index.tsx / index.js above all other imports:

```
 yarn add console-polyfill
```